# How to iteratively compare count data between two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames such as

```
(df1<- data.frame( a=c(1,3,5,6,3),b=c(4,8,5,7,3),c=c(4,5,2,9,5)))
  a b c
1 1 4 4
2 3 8 5
3 5 5 2
4 6 7 9
5 3 3 5

(df2<- data.frame( a=c(2,3,4,9,7),b=c(3,8,5,2,3),c=c(1,7,2,9,4)))
  a b c
1 2 3 1
2 3 8 7
3 4 5 2
4 9 2 9
5 7 3 4
```

I would like to compare the two dfs column-wise i.e. df1$a == df2$a and so on....

And quantify the match==1 & mismatch ==0.....are there any statistical way to prove the difference in the data across the two dfs.....

Comment: What do you want the end result to look like?

Comment: @akash87  if the no of obs is more than these mismatches in some sort of summary form will make more sense than individual mismatch info.....

Answer (score 0):

```
table(as.data.frame(df1 == df2))

, , c = FALSE

       b
a       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     1    1
  TRUE      0    1

, , c = TRUE

       b
a       FALSE TRUE
  FALSE     1    1
  TRUE      0    0
```

This is somewhat i am looking for but it looks too messy...maybe there is a  better way around to get a compact output...

'This a better summarised output

```
sapply(as.data.frame(df1 == df2),function(x) table(x))
      a b c
FALSE 4 2 3
TRUE  1 3 2
```